# How to roundoff float (decimal) values in pandas dataframe that have mixed data types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding, typeerror

In the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = 

contig  pos ref haplotype_block hap_X   hap_Y   odds_ratio  My_hap  Sp_hap
2   2969    C   3706    T   C   0.013000000000000001    C   T
2   3222    G   3706    G   C   -   C   G
2   3416    G   3706    A   G   -   G   A
2   5207    T   1856    T   A   167.922 T   A
2   5238    G   1856    C   G   -   C   G
2   5398    A   1856    A   G   -   A   G
2   5403    A   1856    A   G   -   A   G
2   5426    C   1856    C   A   -   C   A
```

I want to roundoff the values in the `odds_ratio` column. But, some of the data in that column are strings. So I tried using lambda

```
df['odds_ratio'] = df['odds_ratio'].astype(float).round(3)
```

But, I am getting the error message that some of the values (`-`) is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me sometime to find a easy-oneliner, memory efficient solution:

```
df = 

contig  pos ref haplotype_block hap_X   hap_Y   odds_ratio  My_hap  Sp_hap
2   2969    C   3706    T   C   0.013000000000000001    C   T
2   3222    G   3706    G   C   -   C   G
2   3416    G   3706    A   G   -   G   A
2   5207    T   1856    T   A   167.922 T   A
2   5238    G   1856    C   G   -   C   G
2   5398    A   1856    A   G   -   A   G
2   5403    A   1856    A   G   -   A   G
2   5426    C   1856    C   A   -   C   A
```

**Solution:**

```
df['log_odds_ratio'] = df['log_odds_ratio'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 3) if type(x) is float else x)

print(df)

contig  pos ref haplotype_block hap_X   hap_Y   odds_ratio  My_hap  Sp_hap
2   2969    C   3706    T   C   0.013   C   T
2   3222    G   3706    G   C   -   C   G
2   3416    G   3706    A   G   -   G   A
2   5207    T   1856    T   A   167.922 T   A
2   5238    G   1856    C   G   -   C   G
2   5398    A   1856    A   G   -   A   G
2   5403    A   1856    A   G   -   A   G
2   5426    C   1856    C   A   -   C   A
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `to_numeric` and `fillna`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.odds_ratio, 'coerce').round(2).fillna(df.odds_ratio)

0      0.01
1         -
2         -
3    167.92
4         -
5         -
6         -
7         -
Name: odds_ratio, dtype: object
```

Assign it back

```
df.assign(
    odds_ratio=
        pd.to_numeric(df.odds_ratio, 'coerce').round(4).fillna(df.odds_ratio)
)

   contig   pos ref  haplotype_block hap_X hap_Y odds_ratio My_hap Sp_hap
0       2  2969   C             3706     T     C      0.013      C      T
1       2  3222   G             3706     G     C          -      C      G
2       2  3416   G             3706     A     G          -      G      A
3       2  5207   T             1856     T     A    167.922      T      A
4       2  5238   G             1856     C     G          -      C      G
5       2  5398   A             1856     A     G          -      A      G
6       2  5403   A             1856     A     G          -      A      G
7       2  5426   C             1856     C     A          -      C      A
```